# Git, remove local commit that I don't need to push now

Tags: git

I was working in a branch with a lot of commits, 100+

I have merged master into my branch so my branch is up to date with master

I have then gone back into my master and merged my branch into my master.

I'm working in vscode and synchronize changes says I have 0 to pull and 110 to push

I have then been told to squash the commits and merge on github.

So on github I have squashed my commits and merged into master on github.

In vscode it still says I have 0 to pull and 110 to push.

I don't want to push now in vscode do I ?

Can I just remove what it says I can push and just pull from origin master

Comment: do a `git fetch -a` to update your local references of what's on the remote repo in github.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your local `master` branch first with the `github` master.

```
git checkout master
git pull
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Push your branch to github/bitbucket.

Go to **github/bitbucket** and create a `Pull Request` for your branch. Base branch should be `master`.

Verify your changes before merge.

Do a `Squash merge` if all changes looks good.
It will merge all branch commits in a single commit.